# Comparison between various ETL tools

Tags: oracle11g, etl

Very often I get into the projects that have requirements of transferring file data into table. And almost always I've worked at ODI (Oracle Data Integrator) only.

I want to know what are the different ETL tools available and how are they different from ODI and what are the restrictions in each case (like file size limit or column size restriction or processing time etc).

I wish somebody could help.

If somebody can share personal experience on these tools, that would be welcome too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same type of projects that you're in.
Right now I'm working with IBM DataStage. It seems like a good and powerful tool, but it's lacking a good documentation and a strong community.
There's also Pentaho, I have no experience about it, but it seems pretty popular and it's also open source

Comment: that's nice to know. May I also know what the size of your data is and how much time IBM DataStage takes to process that data? By the way, have you worked on ODI?